# iOS LayoutIfNeeded() not returning correct size

Tags: ios, swift, layout

Don't really understand why layoutIfNeeded still doesn't return the correct width for a layout... but however if i get the width by dispatch it will return the correct width. It seems that layoutIfNeeded doesn't layout immediately and rather async. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanks in advance

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool){
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        //incorrect width returned for UIView

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //correct width returned
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When view is done with laying out subviews, delegate method "viewDidLayoutSubviews" is called. In that method or any other method that is called after this method, if you get bounds of view instead of frame(in case of auto layout is enabled), it will return you correct width.

Another thing might help you is that delegate method "viewDidLayoutSubviews" is called before viewWillAppear. It also gets called when you invoke self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Thank you Ali, It helps to clarify whats happening.